# django get_queryset() with conditional filter()

Tags: python, django

I have a custom model manager on model such as:

```
class MyCustomManager(models.Manager):
   def doFoo(self, user, s_format): 
        qs =  super().get_queryset().filter(created_by=user)
        return qs
```

which is returning data based on the `user` passed as the argument. However, how would I go about adding more `AND` conditions to the above query based on `if` conditions? Something like this:

```
class MyCustomManager(models.Manager):
       def doFoo(self, user, s_format): 
            qs =  super().get_queryset().filter(created_by=user)
            if <condition 1>:
                qs.filter(mode='A')
            elif <condition 2>:
                qs.filter(mode='B')
            return qs
```

If I do the above, even if `<condition 2>` is true, it's not generating `created_by=1 AND mode='B'` SQL

I'm basically trying to do the equivalent of the following but split by conditions

```
qs =  super().get_queryset().filter(created_by=user, mode='A')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) returns a *new* queryset, it does *not* alter `qs` itself, you thus should assign the result to `qs` again, or in this case return the queryset constructed by `.filter(…)`:

```
class MyCustomManager(models.Manager):
    def doFoo(self, user, s_format): 
        qs = super().get_queryset().filter(created_by=user)
        if <condition 1>:
            return qs.filter(mode='A')
        elif <condition 2>:
            return qs.filter(mode='B')
        return qs
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to reassign `qs` in your conditions

```
class MyCustomManager(models.Manager):
       def doFoo(self, user, s_format): 
            qs =  super().get_queryset().filter(created_by=user)
            if <condition 1>:
                qs = qs.filter(mode='A')
            elif <condition 2>:
                qs = qs.filter(mode='B')
            return qs
```